# Xamarin BLE Weight scale reading issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

My team and I are new to BLE Android development and we are using C# Xamarin.

We are trying to connect and read the readings on a BLE Weight scale and Oximeter (Berrymed device) and we are able to connect and read the device information but we are not able to read the actual reading, date and time.

We have tried everything but with no luck. Any help or suggestions with C# code samples would really help. we are seeing a lot of Java samples but not Xamarin.

The device is a Chinese HeiTei weight scale

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidBluetoothLE.Bluetooth.Client;
using Java.Util;
public class ReadCharacteristicView : BaseCharacteristicView
    {
        private BluetoothGattCharacteristic _characteristic;
        private DeviceReadingHandler _readingHandler;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ReadCharacteristicView);

            InitializeView();
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            _readingHandler.Dispose();
        }

        private void InitializeView()
        {
            var connectionHandler = BluetoothClient.Instance.ConnectionHandler;
            _readingHandler = new DeviceReadingHandler(connectionHandler.GattValue, GattClientObserver.Instance);
            _characteristic = GetCharacteristic(connectionHandler.GetServiceList());

            var readButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ReadCharacteristicButton);
            readButton.Click += ReadButtonOnClick;
        }

        private BluetoothGattCharacteristic GetCharacteristic(IEnumerable<BluetoothGattService> serviceList)
        {
            var uuid = (UUID)Intent.GetSerializableExtra("Characteristic");

            var service = serviceList.First(s => s.Characteristics.Any(ch => ch.Uuid.Equals(uuid)));
            return service.Characteristics.First(ch => ch.Uuid.Equals(uuid));
        }

        private void ReadButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var hexText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.HexReadText);
            var stringText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.StringReadText);

            ShowDialog("Start reading...");
            _readingHandler.Read(_characteristic, (bytes, status) => RunOnUiThread(() => 
            {
                if (status != GattStatus.Success)
                {
                    ShowDialog("Reading failed with status: " + status);
                    return;
                }

                hexText.SetText(BitConverter.ToString(bytes), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                stringText.SetText(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                ShowDialog("Read Success!");
            }));
        }

        private void ShowDialog(string message)
        {
            DialogView.ShowDialog(message, this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Comment: Do you have the details of the BLE device of the scale?  Do you have any device that can read it (e.g., a PC?)   It may use a specific service / characteristic or a generic one

Comment: If not, you might start with an app such as LightBlue by Punch Through -- you can see what Services & Characteristics are available, and maybe even read them.

Comment: Avoid saying "We have tried everything" especially when not showing even the beginning of the list of things you have tried.

Comment: The BLE weight scale is a Chinese make - Universal Weights - HeiTei scale. This is the code we are using